# Using JSON to write data to multiple tables

Tags: c#, json, webapi

Could you please assist me?  I am still a newbie at coding.  I have been trying to build an invoice form using Angular 11, and then using JSON to send the data to my web API, and then finally to write the data to a SQL database.

I have 2 classes -  Invoice and InvoiceLineItems

```
 public class CustomerInvoice : BaseEntity
    {
        public string InvoiceNumber { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateRaised { get; set; }
        public DateTime PaymentDueDate { get; set; }
        public int SubTotal { get; set; }
        public string DiscountDescription { get; set; }
        public int DiscountFactor { get; set; }
        public int DiscountAmount { get; set; }
        public int TotalDiscount { get; set; }
        public int GrandTotal { get; set; }
        public FamilyGroup FamilyGroup { get; set; }
        public int FamilyGroupId { get; set; }
        public List<CustomerInvoiceLine> CustomerInvoiceLines { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class CustomerInvoiceLine: BaseEntity
    {
        public SchoolFee SchoolFee { get; set; }
        public int SchoolFeeId { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public int Amount { get; set; }
        public CustomerInvoice CustomerInvoice { get; set; }
        public int CustomerInvoiceId { get; set; }
    }
```

I have 2 DTO's (1 for each class above)

```
public class CustomerInvoiceAddDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string InvoiceNumber { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateRaised { get; set; }
        public DateTime PaymentDueDate { get; set; }
        public int SubTotal { get; set; }
        public string DiscountDescription { get; set; }
        public int DiscountFactor { get; set; }
        public int DiscountAmount { get; set; }
        public int TotalDiscount { get; set; }
        public int GrandTotal { get; set; }
        public int FamilyGroupId { get; set; }   
    }
```

and

```
public class CustomerInvoiceLineAddDto
    {
        public int SchoolFeeId { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public int Amount { get; set; }
        public int CustomerInvoiceId { get; set; }
    }
```

My controller for Adding the Invoice:

```
[HttpPost("addInvoice")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> AddInvoice(CustomerInvoiceAddDto invoiceAdd)
        {
            CustomerInvoice invoice = new CustomerInvoice();
            _mapper.Map(invoiceAdd, invoice);
            await _unitOfWork.CustomerInvoiceRepository.AddCustomerInvoiceAsync(invoice);

            var createdInvoice = await _context.CustomerInvoices
                    .Where(s => s.FamilyGroupId == invoiceAdd.FamilyGroupId )
                    .OrderBy(g => g.Id)
                    .LastOrDefaultAsync();
            return Ok(createdInvoice.Id);
        }
```

And for adding the Invoice Line Items:

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> AddCustomerInvoiceLines(CustomerInvoiceLineAddDto[] invoiceLinesAddDto)
        {
            var invoiceLineDetails = _mapper.Map<List<CustomerInvoiceLine>>(invoiceLinesAddDto);
            await _unitOfWork.CustomerInvoiceLineRepository.AddCustomerInvoiceLinesAsync(invoiceLineDetails);
            return Ok();
        }
```

PROBLEM:  When I initially designed this, I was going to call an API to add the invoice first, and then return the invoice ID to the front-end.  Thereafter I would call the InvoiceLineItems controller to create the Invoice Line Items.

However, in my front-end, I have 1 API call in JSON format as follows:

```
{
    "DateRaised": "2022-03-01T21:32:13.000Z",
    "PaymentDueDate": "2022-03-08T21:32:13.000Z",
    "FamilyGroupId": 12,
    "subTotal": 1500,
    "discountFactor": "2",
    "discountAmount": 0,
    "discountDescription": null,
    "totalDiscount": 0,
    "grandTotal": 1500,
    "invoiceLineItems": [
        {
            "schoolFeeId": 1,
            "quantity": "1",
            "unitPrice": "1500"
        },
        {
            "schoolFeeId": 2,
            "quantity": "1",
            "unitPrice": "3000"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is it possible to have a Controller that can take the 1 JSON call and write to the Invoice table, return the Invoice ID, and then write to the InvoiceLineItems (array of Line Items)?

Thanks again!

Comment: a point on your design: why not get  await _unitOfWork.CustomerInvoiceRepository.AddCustomerInvoiceAsync(invoice); to return the created invoice instead of then going back to the db and retrieving it, you should also have a test in place anyway that the operation was a success or not, you also dont mention which date access middleware you are using, i presume EF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `CustomerInvoiceLineAddDto` as a property in `CustomerInvoiceAddDto` like below-

```
public class CustomerInvoiceAddDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string InvoiceNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateRaised { get; set; }
    public DateTime PaymentDueDate { get; set; }
    public int SubTotal { get; set; }
    public string DiscountDescription { get; set; }
    public int DiscountFactor { get; set; }
    public int DiscountAmount { get; set; }
    public int TotalDiscount { get; set; }
    public int GrandTotal { get; set; }
    public int FamilyGroupId { get; set; }   
    public List<CustomerInvoiceLineAddDto> CustomerInvoiceLineDto {get;set;}
}
```

and keep your Angular JSON format as it is.

then in your action method do something like it.

I modified your code assuming you have code something like-

```
  [HttpPost("addInvoice")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> AddInvoice(CustomerInvoiceAddDto invoiceAdd)
    {
        CustomerInvoice invoice = new CustomerInvoice();
        _mapper.Map(invoiceAdd, invoice);
        await _unitOfWork.CustomerInvoiceRepository.AddCustomerInvoiceAsync(invoice);

        var createdInvoice = await _context.CustomerInvoices
                .Where(s => s.FamilyGroupId == invoiceAdd.FamilyGroupId)
                .OrderBy(g => g.Id)
                .LastOrDefaultAsync();

        var invoiceLineDetails = _mapper.Map<List<CustomerInvoiceLine>>(invoiceAdd.CustomerInvoiceLineDto);

        foreach (var line in invoiceLineDetails)
        {
            line.CustomerInvoiceId = createdInvoice.Id;
        }

        await _unitOfWork.CustomerInvoiceLineRepository.AddCustomerInvoiceLinesAsync(invoiceLineDetails);

        return Ok(createdInvoice.Id);
    }
```

Comment: if ```CustomerInvoiceLineDto``` is ```List/array``` update your mapper as per requirement.

Comment: Hi Gyanendra,  Thanks a million for your response.  I am able to get the code to work if there is only 1 Invoice Line Item.  However, how do I get the Controller to accommodate multiple line items?

Comment: Your controller will accept multiple line item as this ```public List<CustomerInvoiceLineAddDto> CustomerInvoiceLineDto {get;set;}``` is of list type. also, Is your line item will have same ```createdInvoice.Id``` ?

Comment: Updated answer to accommodate multiple line items. you need to create a method in your ```_unitOfWork.CustomerInvoiceRepository``` to add line item as ```array/list```

Comment: Hi Gyanendra.  I have a method called AddCustomerInvoiceLines that takes an array of invoice line items.  I tested this method in Postman and it works perfectly.  However, the test I did in Postman assumed that the InvoiceLineItems was an independent array and not included with the Invoice object.  How would I change the AddCustomerInvoiceLines method (or the AddCustomerInvoice method) to get the array out of the JSON object?

Comment: Already updated the answer for the same this ```invoiceAdd.CustomerInvoiceLineDto``` will extract the lines JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ExecuteScalar to get back the ID for the line inserted.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).